# Simple inference rule in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm currently learning how to use makefiles. But I'm struggling with % pattern rules. I've boiled down my failing makefile to this very simple example:

I fill an empty directory with:

```
echo aaa > a.in && echo bbb > b.in
```

A first makefile like this works very well:

```
a.out : a.in
    cat $< > $@
```

as

```
make && echo *.out && cat *.out
```

returns

```
cat a.in > a.out
a.out
aaa
```

but when I try to use a pattern rule modifying the makefile as follows:

```
%.out : %.in
    cat $< > $@
```

make then returns me:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

It seems like a very simple problem but I can't get to what I am missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a makefile with no targets lists (only patterns), and you just type `make`, then you haven't told make that it should build anything specific, so it won't do anything.

A pattern rule doesn't mean "go find all the files that match this pattern and build them".  A pattern rule tells make "if you need to find a way to build a file that matches this target pattern, then here's how you do it".

If you type `make a.out` so make knows that you want to build a target `a.out`, then make will use your pattern rule to build it.

Alternatively, you can add the target to your makefile, something like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all: a.out

%.out : %.in
        cat $< > $@
```

Comment: Ok I see where was the problem, so is there a way to make it actually do "go find all the files that match this pattern and build them"? I just tried: "all: *.out" but it didn't worked...

Comment: You can use the `wildcard` function: `all: $(wildcard *.out)`.  Personally I don't like these kinds of makefiles; I prefer to list out the files (either source or target files) specifically.  Too much room for error otherwise.  But YMMV.